# flutter android alarm manager plus plugin throws error when calling initializer function?

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm trying to use android alarm manager plus in my flutter app to schedule some local notifications. I started with simple AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(..) function. And I"m calling intialize function in main method.

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

that `await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();` cause the error. Error is

```
E/flutter (10486): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method AlarmService.start on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/android_alarm_manager)
```

So I'm as I read some other issues, the problem is with pluginregistrar is not registering AlarmService. So I have to add a native code to Application file. But my project doesn't have Application.java file.
All I have is

1.flutter_project_root\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

```
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  private static final String TAG = "GeneratedPluginRegistrant";
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    try {
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin android_alarm_manager_plus, dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin", e);
    }
  }
}
```

2.flutter_root\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\snooze_test\MainActivity.kt

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

I don't know native code. How should fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the required file in `AndroidMenifest.xml`
location project -> android->app->src->main->

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tmdp_getx_mvc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<!-- For apps with targetSDK=31 (Android 12) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
   <application
        android:label="tmdp_getx_mvc"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
              
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more detail refer: https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus
After update manifest file once uninstall and install app from device

Comment: I added them in manifest file.

Comment: Now any challenges? @ShehanDMG

Comment: I already had them in the code. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I think there is another issue, can you please tell me your device version? so I can run and tell you about the more detail? if you don't mind

Comment: emulator - pixel 4 api 24

Comment: not sure why it worked when I cold booted the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It worked without changing anything after I cold booted the emulator.